# Image is not showing in my custom grid of Magento 1.9.4.3

Tags: magento-1.9, php, renderer, custom-grid

I am trying to add an Image using my custom admin form. The image is saved while uploading it via custom admin form. But does not displays in the admin grid image column of my custom-created module. Here is the screenshot.
[image]
As you can see my image has been saved using my custom admin form. The src of an image is generated and the image is been displayed in the my custom created form.

[image]
But the image does not displyed in the admin grid. I had created the renderer to get the image but it doe not work for me. The renderer doesn't generate the src of my image.
Please check my code below:

Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn("image", array(
        "header"    => Mage::helper("news")->__("Image"),
        "type"      => "text",
        "width"     => "150px",
        "index"     => "image",
        "renderer" => "Custom_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Grid_Renderer_Image",
    ));
```

Custom/News/Block/Adminhtml/News/Grid/Renderer/Image.php

```
class Custom_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Grid_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $val = Mage::helper('news/news')->init($row, 'thumbnail')->resize(100);
    $out = '<img src=". $val ." width="100px" height="100px"/>';
    return $out;
}   }
```

Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
        "label"     => Mage::helper("news")->__("Image"),
        "name"      => "image",
        "note" => "(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)",
      ));
```

NewsController.php

```
try {   //Save Image
try {
    if ((bool) $postData['image']['delete'] == 1) {
        $postData['image'] = '';
    } else {
        unset($postData['image']);
        if (isset($_FILES)) {
            if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")) {
                    $model = Mage::getModel("news/news")->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                    if ($model->getData('image')) {
                        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                        $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . implode(DS, explode('/', $model->getData('image'))));
                    }
                }
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'news' . DS . 'news' . DS;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $destFile = $path . $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $fileName = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                $uploader->save($path, $fileName);
                $postData['image'] = "news/news/".$fileName;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
    return;
}
```

Can anyone please help me to get it solved. I had refered this [this](https://inchoo.net/magento/show-product-thumbnail-in-grids/) post to create renderer for my custom grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research and debugging my custom code. I found the solution, and it worked fine for me.

I had applied changes in my renderer, and it gave me the image path and now I am able to display an image in my custom grid `Custom/News/Block/Adminhtml/News/Grid/Renderer/Image.php`

```
Class Custom_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Grid_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $img = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    if ($img && strpos($img, 'no_selection') !== 0) {
        return sprintf('<img src="%s" width="60px" />', Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$img);
    }
    return '';
}   }
```

Please check the below screenshot of my custom grid.

[image]
Please check and vote for my answer if you feel helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Hii @AshokDubariya thanks for edit.